# char array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

In C++ can I read from file which contains integers and store it in a char array[] ?

Comment: Yes, you can.  You explain your desired input and output better?

Comment: Agreed -- specifically, whether you want formatted or unformatted I/O.

Comment: Internally does that mean the integers are stored in ASCII format?!

Comment: What does "store it in a char array[]" mean?

Comment: @sasi : That's what we're asking you.

Comment: Is it a text file or a binary file?   (Can you open it with notepad and see the numbers or do you see funny characters).

Comment: I have a coulmn of integers stored in a text file. I want to read those integers into an array. But I want to be able to store those integers as char in order to manipulate them using their ASCII code. My question is to know if those integers are read using fread from file.txt to a char buf[] are they automatically stored inside the computer in ASCII format?!

Comment: What is the allowed range of the numbers?

Comment: And how do you want the numbers delimited?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to store numbers from a file in a `char` array:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");
    char arr[100];
    char* end = std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(in),
                          std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                          arr);
    return 0;
}
```

There are two issues here. One, you must know at compile time the size of your array. Two, each of the input numbers must fit into a `char`. Note that this is formatted input, so the valid range is not 0-255 or even 0-127. It's a valid character, so '0', '2', 'a', 'C' and so on are valid inputs for each character.

Maybe what you want is to read your file into a `std::vector<std::string>`?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(in),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              std::back_inserter(vec));
    std::transfrom(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                   vec.begin(),
                   my_transform());
    return 0;
}
```

Here we read the numbers into *`std::vector<std::string>`*. Then, we manipulate each string representation of a number through the `my_transform` functor. You define the functor as a simple struct that defines `std::string operator()(const std::string&)`. The function-call operator takes a number and is expected to return the manipulation of the number, however you wish to change the number.

Comment: Updated to reflect on using a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a `char` array, because I think that's what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as your integers are small enough to be represented as a byte. If not, they higher order bytes will likely be lost.